# How do I export a table I created through a Join query in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I entered a join query into PHPMyAdmin and created a table. How do I export it?

I seem to only be able to export existing tables, not generated ones.

Comment: I assume you imply you generated a "result set", not a table, right?

Comment: A join query does not intrinsically create a table.  It creates a result set.  You'll probably have to post your SQL here, but if you did something like 'SELECT * from foo JOIN bar ON (foo.id=bar.id)', all you need to do is 'CREATE TABLE foobar as SELECT * SELECT * from foo JOIN bar ON (foo.id=bar.id)'.  Of course, then you need to deal with indexes and whatnot.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which version of PHPMyAdmin (mine's 3.3.9) you're using, but after running your query you should see a grey box at the bottom labeled "Query results operations."  In that box is a link for "export."

Answer (score 1):

I'm using phpmyadmin 4.8.5 and the export to sql option still not showing.

Two potential workarounds:

1. As [John_Green](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131305/how-do-i-export-a-table-i-created-through-a-join-query-in-phpmyadmin#comment12986600_10131305) suggests, create a new table with the results and then export that table:

e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar AS
SELECT * FROM foo
JOIN bar ON (foo.id = bar.id)
```

2. Run the query in [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) in the Result Grid select Export button, then switch to .sql file. You will be prompted with a table name to use.